# Magento 2: Add Logo upload field in admin shipping method section

Tags: magento2, admin, shipping-methods, logo

I have implementing logo upload field in admin shipping method section, but facing issue.
Any have uploaded same Logo/Image upload field in shipping method section in admin then let me know.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the steps below to get the upload field section under the Free Shipping section.**

**Step 1:** Create a file system.xml under following path

> Vendorname\Modulename\etc\adminhtml\

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">  
 <system>  
 <section id="carriers">  
 <group id="freeshipping">  
 <field id="bg_login_page" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">  
     <label>Background Login Page</label>  
     <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>  
     <upload_dir config="system/filesystem/media" scope_info="1">imagesProfile/backend/images</upload_dir>  
     <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">imagesProfile/backend/images</base_url>  
     <comment><![CDATA[Allowed file types: jpeg, gif, png.]]></comment>  
 </field>  
 </group>  
 </section>  
 </system>
```

**Step 2:** Run Magento basic commands.

> Above solution work for to add custom field under free shipping section. If you want to add in other Delivery methods section, change field id according to same.
>
> *Hope it helps :)*

Comment: Need to add shipping Logo/Image field in all the shipping method using dynamic functionality and also it should be visible on frontend checkout page shipping method section. Hope you have understand the requirements.